# How to create minimax algorithm in dart

Tags: dart, minimax

I need to create a chess AI, I have read about various algorithms and ways to build a bot using tensorflow. But i chose minimax because of it's simplicity. I need the code to do make a minimax algorithm, I can't find any online tutorials that help with it and searched pub.dev for a minimax algorithm but couldn't find any. Please help

Answer (score 0):

take a look at wikipedias pseudocode example:

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Minimax#Pseudocode